# SSAS - Ignore "attribute key not found" error

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2012

I have a cube which is unable to process anymore because of a missing key in a dimension.

The process cube action kept returning the following error message:

> The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'MyFactTableName', Column: 'MyDimensionKey', Value: 'Value'. The attribute is 'MyDimensionKey'.

To explain the situation: I have a fact table FactSales with multiple columns of which ProductID is one. ProductID is a key from the table DimProducts.

The problem however is that one record in the fact table has a productID, which does not exist in DimProduct.
The problem lies with the ETL, but I have no access to that and the one having access is not available for 2 weeks. I only have the SSAS project I can work with.

So my question: is there a way (a property in the dimension/attributes etc for example) to temporarily ignore this error and still process the cube? I heard about settings that can be set in SSMS when processing manually, but this has to be done daily (with a SQL job) too, so I am looking for an option in my SSAS solution itself

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways. When you process the cube, in the processing options you can specifically set to ignore dimension errors and continue.

Likewise,i think you can set this in processing options in visual studio for the dimension.

Longer term, it may be wise to change the etl so that any missing keys are assigned to a generic missing key to prevent further cube processing errors and let you fix the error properly